# Need an inverted semicircle as an accent mark over a character

Tags: macros, symbols

I need to write a macro (something like \semicircle{{#1}} )
to place an inverted semicircle symbol as an accent mark to be placed over a character, using a \stackrel comand.
The \frown symbol is too flat, and the \cap symbol is too tight, so the choice is a down facing side semicircle sitting
opve rthe character(s).
The semicircle should spreard over all the characters (one or two) that are placed for #1 in the macro  - something like \semicircle{X} or \semicircle (XY}  etc.
Is TikZ a good choice?
Any help in building such a macrio will be apprecieated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would you obtain a `breve` diacritic mark,  per chance?

Comment: In the MWE given below,  I need an "inverted semicircle" symbol, instead of the "frown" symbol" \documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\semicircle}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\frown}{\mbox{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\semicircle{A},  \semicircle{AB}
\end{document}